# Any possibility to add subtitl in AxWindowsMediaPlayer control?

Tags: compact-framework, .net-2.0, windows-media-player, wmp

I am using axWindowsMediaPlayer control in my windows mobile application with using .net CF 2.0, 
I want to play the video with subtitle.(SRT file type) 
Any one know how to add the SRT file in AxWindowMediaPlaye ,It is possible ?

Pl. give me some suggestions

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Wrong flag, WMP's playback has nothing to do with .Net. use windows-media-player instead

Answer (score 0):

Yes, [write](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa451221.aspx) or find a DirectShow filter that displays the subtitle. You can also [write your own player](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/SimplePlayer).

For ASF playback (e.g. wmv, wma) on PC you need to [add a script stream to the file](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/267510). Not sure if the mobile version of WMP supports captioning.

Answer (score 0):

As I know the Windows Media Player doesn't suuport the SubRip SRT-Files, but the smi (SAMI-Files, closed captions). I use the smi-file to show the multi-language subtitles. You can covert very easy your srt to the smi, or create your own smi subtitles, using a free "Subtitle Workshop" tool.

You can also add another language to the smi, here is some samples: [Captioning for Windows Media](http://webaim.org/techniques/captions/windows/sami).
You can also change the language of the subtitles using the closedCaption properties, like

```
AxWindowsMediaPlayer.closedCaption.SAMILang = "German";
```

or set the smi-file direclty

```
AxWindowsMediaPlayer.closedCaption.SAMIFileName = "subtitles.smi";
```